# how to slide images in a block in drupal 7

Tags: image, module, drupal-7, block

Is there any module in drupal 7 that provides image sliding. My images are in a block. It has about 10 images positioned horizontally and there will be arrows at the end of blocks that will slide images left or right. Images will slide only if arrows are clicked. Is there any module doing that job in drupal 7?

Comment: You can also check for this link for more ideas
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/97766/creating-image-slider-in-drupal-7

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Views Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) module and the related modules that are linked on that page.